# Removing -ObjC flag from cordova/phonegap builds

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Is there a way to de-activate the `-ObjC` flag found in xcode Build Settings > Linking > Other Linker Flags at the CLI build step?

Having this flag causes linking errors. I have been able to remove it manually and build via xcode however this is part of an automated build process using a grunt phonegap plugin (wrapping the phonegap cli). Is there any way to control the linker flags from the cli?

Answer (score 0):

After diving into the [Cordova CLI internals](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/blob/master/src/cli.js), I was able to find out that there is a possibility to any parameters that are passed downstream as follows (starting on line 141)

```
var unparsedArgs = [];
var parseStopperIdx = args.argv.original.indexOf('--');
if (parseStopperIdx != -1) {
  unparsedArgs = args.argv.original.slice(parseStopperIdx + 1);
}
```

If I correctly understood the purpose of this is to allow such usage and it would be possible to add any parameters you wish for build.

Now, as I don't really know anything about iOS or Objective-C, I can't tell you which parameter would be the one to be passed to prevent this from being happened, but quick googling revealed a *-all_load* might be the right one.

So you would use it with something like

```
cordova build ios ---all_load
```

Also if there existed an option to set to false and thus prevent it's usage, you could do something like this

```
cordova build ios ---ObjC=false
```

but I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into this. I've also come across some references to xcconfig files which can be used to configure anything in the build panel apparently. I just need to find out how they could be integrated into the build task

Comment: @hellosmithy: Again, without any expertise on this area, I suppose the _xcconfig_ files are for XCode, and will thus be not taken into account whilst using CLI utilities. But please do not only trust me on this manner.